# Rails + Paperclip not giving image url in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I am setting up a basic blog with an optional image upload for the posts. The images are being uploaded properly and going to the right directory. However, when I go to the view it loads the default image:

```
photos/original/missing.png
```

Here is the model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :date, :feature, :poster, :title, :photo

  has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" },
                    :url  => "/assets/posts/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                    :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/posts/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"

  attr_accessor :photo_file_name
  attr_accessor :photo_content_type
  attr_accessor :photo_file_size
  attr_accessor :photo_updated_at
end
```

And in the view:

```
<%= image_tag @post.photo.url %>
```

For example, I upload an image with a post, and it gets uploaded to:

```
rails_root/public/assets/posts/5/original/image.jpg
rails_root/public/assets/posts/5/medium/image.jpg
rails_root/public/assets/posts/5/thumb/image.jpg
```

Migration

```
class AddAttachmentImageToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_attachment :posts, :photo
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :posts, :photo
  end
end
```

Schema:

```
  create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "date"
    t.string   "poster"
    t.boolean  "feature"
    t.datetime "created_at",         :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         :null => false
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
  end
```

Yet when the view is rendered, it can't find the image. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Try attr_accessible instead of attr_accessor for the photo columns.

so

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :body, :date, :feature, :poster, :title, :photo, :photo_file_name, :photo_content_type, :photo_file_size, :photo_updated_at

  has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" },
                :url  => "/assets/posts/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/posts/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
end
```

EDIT AFTER UPDATE:

There is a mismatch between your DB and your paperclip settings. Either change all the columns to photo_x or change your settings that say photo to image.

Comment: This is what I originally had. When I do this I get:

Post model missing required attr_accessor for 'photo_file_name'

Comment: What does your schema look like for Post? What I think is happening is your missing one of those columns in your DB. So the problem seems to go away when you add an accessor, but of course because nothing is getting saved to the DB when you load the object again the data relating to the uploaded object is lost so it assume there isn't something uploaded.

Comment: Edited to add migration and schema.

Comment: I think i see the problem. The schema lists "image" where everything else says "photo".